# Ramanuja and Chellapillai

Tags: puranas, ramanujacharya

When Moghuls invaded Bharat desa, a daughter of moghul emperor took the utsava vigraha of Thriunarayana perumal [Melkot in Karnataka] and was playing with that utsava vigraha. On seeing this Ramanujacharya  told the moghul emperor to give back the vigraha. Sarcastically the moghul told that you call your God. If he comes alongwith you take the vigraha. Ramanuja sang Chellapillai come along with me; Immediately the vigraha followed Ramanuja. All got astonished. Does this have any referral in puranas? If so in which purana?

Comment: "Moghuls invaded Bharat desa, a daughter of Moghul emperor.." - Moghuls invaded in 16th century (1510s or thereabouts), Ramanujua lived in the 12th century. I think you are talking Delhi Sultans who came earlier.

Comment: Every religion has deepest devotees from those full of deep faith. All have miracles. Miracles are inseparable from faith श्रद्धा .

Answer (score 3):

As much as I know, there is no referral of the Chellapillai incident in the Puranas. This is because Ananthazhwan (Ananta Sesha) had taken Avatharam as Ramanuja much much longer after the Puranas had been written by Vyasa. To be precise, in 1017 AD.

Comment: This is not the relevant answer. The question is related to Vishnu leela which has been mentioned in a purana. Please post you answer as comment. If you put in answer column you should cite sources.

Comment: You need to share references while answering this shall be turned into a comment otherwise.

Comment: Dear Dr. Vineet, Kindly advise me on sharing references and adding citations as this is my first day at HSE.. Thank you

Comment: Dear Parthsarathy, Kindly mention the Vishnu Leela, which is in accordance with your question, as Ramanuja was born much much longer after the Puranas were written, as mentioned in my answer...

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal This is the correct answer. This doesn't really doesn't require any citations. It's a known fact that Ramanujacharya was born 1000 years ago. It is like asking Narendra Modi becoming PM of India mentioned in which Purana.

Comment: Dear Sarvabhouma, Yes, that is the point I am trying to stress upon, the fact that Ramanuja was born much much longer after the Puranas were written

Comment: Sarvabhouma and you can conclusively say that no Puranas were being re-written or modified 1000 years ago? There are loads of interpolations from much later time periods in many puranas so how can a statement be called the correct answer without any support?

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal If some Purana is modified in past 1000 years, that isn't called a Purana, it's called an interpolation. Interpolations have no value.We can expect some prophecies regarding birth of some great personality but expecting each and every incident as a prophecy is foolish.Regarding references, the reference is Ramanujacharya born in 11th century. Anything modified in that century is considered as interpolation as it was neither Vyasa nor his shishyas who did it. Reference need not to be a copy paste sentence or an external link. It should support what is said in the answer.

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal yes, as Sarvabhouma mentioned, we are talking about the original work...

Answer (score 0):

Read the footnote in the clip to save time.
*emphasized text*I am lucky to able to find a reference (not Puranic, but by a respected Sadhu) from the book written by an eminent sadhu of the Ramakrishna panth. - "The Life of Ramanuja ". - Swami Ramkrishnananda....
"[image: Chellapillai walks to Sri Ramanuja]

Hope this gives some light to a wonderful Leela, which was searching for us to know about it.

Comment: Saving the Lord SriRanganathaswami , from Malik Kafur another example.